# What is the difference between Hyperledger sawtooth core and Hyperledger sawtooth sabre?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-sawtooth

I am new to blockchain technologies. We have bided against the potential project on hyperledger. So I was reading the documentation of hyperledger Sawtooth. In the documentation, I found Sawtooth core and Sawtooth Sabre. From the documentation , in a layman term I can make out that Sawtooth core provides you the platform and Sawtooth Sabre is a way making smart contracts.

My question is :

1. Is my understanding right?
2. Can I use smart contracts i.e. Sawtooth Sabre with Sawtooth core.(Any documentation, any reference, please provide)
3. Can you please point out some good study materials for the same.
4. Is Sawtooth is the right choice instead of fabric.

Comment: https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:LinuxFoundationX+LFS171x+3T2018/course/

Comment: Yo can do this course for all hyperledger frameworks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Is my understanding right?

   No Hyperledger sawtooth core provides smart contracts but they are known as transaction processors and 2nd thing sabre is providing you the transaction processor where you can write your logic in webassambly.

   Sawtooth provides two additional transaction families which provides you the way to write smart contracts in solidity(seth) and webassembly(sabre).

   Otherwise you have to create your own transaction families using one of the SDKs that sawtooth provides. So you can write the smart contracts in javascript, python, Go, and rust. Sabre is just a way to supporting websassembly for contracts.
2. Can I use smart contracts i.e. Sawtooth Sabre with Sawtooth core.(Any documentation, any reference, please provide)

   https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/sabre/releases/latest/sabre_transaction_family.html (i have this reference only)
3. Can you please point out some good study materials for the same.

   For Hyperledger sawtooth this is a good YouTube playlist.
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RaRK_gKckkE&list=PLCDDZcRbrd6JYNcwENh1aR2NmlxmmGM7k

   For Processors and transaction performing please check the below documentation
   https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/1.0/app_developers_guide.html
4. Is Sawtooth is the right choice instead of fabric.

   That depends on the case study if you want more information please check below articles

   [What's the difference between Hyperledger Fabric and Sawtooth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47023945/whats-the-difference-between-hyperledger-fabric-and-sawtooth)

   https://www.skcript.com/svr/should-i-choose-hyperledger-sawtooth-1-0-over-fabric-1-0/

   https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/71312/hyperledger-fabric-vs-sawtooth-lake-which-platform-is-appropriate-for-supply-cha

   https://hackernoon.com/know-hyperledger-fabric-then-moving-to-sawtooth-is-easy-15445f902493

Answer (score 1):

`Hyperledger` has multiple independent blockchain platforms. The main platforms are `Hyperledger Fabric` and `Hyperledger Sawtooth`.

`Seth` is an implementation Ethereum VM running on Hyperledger Sawtooth. It uses the code from `Hyperledger Burrow` for the EVM part, but runs on top of Sawtooth.